# How to retrieve information from MySQL immediately after updating it?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a frontend that displays a list of tasks taken from a database and a form that allows the user to update it. I want to update the frontend with the new list after a new task has been added. I have tried performing a search query after the creation query and sending the information to the frontend but it returns the previous value.

```
app.post(
    "/addTask",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
      Task.create({
        description: req.body.data,
        user_id: req.user.dataValues.user_id
      }).then(
        Task.findAll({
          where: { user_id: req.user.dataValues.user_id }
        }).then(data => {
          console.log("HERE: ", data); // logs [], initial value when no tasks
          res.status(200).json(data);
        })
      );
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this?

```js
app.post(
  "/addTask",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Task.create({
      description: req.body.data,
      user_id: req.user.dataValues.user_id
    }).then(result => {
      Task.findAll({
        where: { user_id: req.user.dataValues.user_id }
      }).then(data => {
        console.log("HERE: ", data); // logs [], initial value when no tasks
        res.status(200).json(data);
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't need to specify a parameter on the callback so I went with ```() => Task.findAll...```

Comment: @AlbertoVilches yes since we didn't use result variable () also works.

Answer (score 0):

Someone more theoretically inclined might explain it better...but in my observations,  `then()` doesn't wait until the `create()` is complete **unless you pass a parameter**.  As illustrated below, if you pass newTask from `create()` to the `then()`, the newly created task will appear in the `findall()` result.

```
app.post(
    "/addTask",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
      Task.create({
        description: req.body.data,
        user_id: req.user.dataValues.user_id
      }).then(
        newTask=> {  // added *************
        Task.findAll({
          where: { user_id: req.user.dataValues.user_id }
        }).then(data => {
          console.log("HERE: ", data); // logs [], initial value when no tasks
          res.status(200).json(data);
        })
      }  // added ***********************
      );
    }
  );
```

HTH